# Use of twiml attribute in Client.calls.create()l

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api

I am new on Twilio and I was trying to use the following tutorial:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-make-outbound-phone-calls-python

Using the twiml attribute instead of Url:

```
call = client.calls.create(
                        twiml='<Response><Say>Ahoy, World!</Say></Response>',
                        to='+YYYYYYYYY',
                        from_='+XXXXXXXXX'
                    )
```

When I launched it, I received the following error:

```
responded with an error: error processing request: create() got an unexpected keyword argument 'twiml'
```

Is twiml deprecated? I use the last version of Twilio and Python 2.7. It seems really odd to me since the tutorial was made in January 2020.

Comment: We've just had the latest version released since you wrote this question. Can you try again with version 6.35.5?

Comment: Yes I reinstall Twilio 6.35.5 and now is working, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the twiml attribute for calls create is a newer feature, and thus requires a more recent version of the Twilio Helper Library. You can use url (if you cannot upgrade), which has existed for some time and takes a URL which returns TwiML.

[Pass TwiML with Call Initiation Requests GA](https://www.twilio.com/changelog/pass-twiml-call-initiation-requests)

[[2019-12-12] Version 6.35.0](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-python/blob/master/CHANGES.md#2019-12-12-version-6350)